# How to specify :defaults for several routes in Rails 3 in a DRY way?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have several routes like these:

```rb
get '/test1' => 'test#index1', defaults: {common: '123'}
get '/test2' => 'test#index2', defaults: {common: '123'}
```

And specs for them like these:

```rb
specify do
  get('/test1').should route_to controller: 'test', action: 'index1', common: '123'
end
specify do
  get('/test2').should route_to controller: 'test', action: 'index2', common: '123'
end
```

How to DRY up the usage of defaults?

I've tried using `with_options` like this:

```rb
with_options defaults: {common: '123'} do |o|
  o.get '/test1' => 'test#index1'
  o.get '/test2' => 'test#index2'
end
```

But it breaks the first test with message:

```
Failure/Error: get('/test1').should route_to controller: 'test', action: 'index1', common: '123'
       The recognized options <{"common"=>"123", "controller"=>"test", "action"=>"index2"}> did not match <{"controller"=>"test", "action"=>"index1", "common"=>"123"}>, difference: <{"action"=>"index1"}>.
       <{"controller"=>"test", "action"=>"index1", "common"=>"123"}> expected but was
       <{"common"=>"123", "controller"=>"test", "action"=>"index2"}>.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not `with_options` here, `defaults` accepts block as well:

```
defaults common: '123' do
  get '/test1' => 'test#index1'
  get '/test2' => 'test#index2'
end
```

Comment: I've trusted highlighting of my editor too much. It didn't highlight `defaults` as a known method when I typed it and I believed it. Shouldn't have.
Thank you.